# Can I run QGis from the command line on OSX?

Tags: macos

I want to run [QGis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) from the command line in OSX (so that I can [create a high-resolution image of a project](http://anitagraser.com/2010/11/30/creating-high-resolution-images-using-qgis/)).

But lots of Googling has convinced me that it may not be possible in OSX. Does anyone know if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. It's even in the "[Getting Started](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#label-startingqgis)" documentation:

> Double click the icon in your Applications folder. If you need to
>   start QGIS in a shell, run
>   /path-to-installation-executable/Contents/MacOS/Qgis.